# Possible focus issue with CefSharp winforms solution

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Using CfSharp Winforms version 73.1.130.0, I've created a very simple application which consists of a main form with browser controls which then spawns new forms each with their own browser control in them.

The main form points to a web page which has a simple link in it, the link when clicked calls a c# method with a URL and a window identifier, the c# method is registered in the application using ChromeBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject.  The method either creates a new form (if one with the same identifier doesn't exist) or brings the form with the identifier to the front using BringToFront().

We are finding on some machines that calling BringToFront() is causing the main form and the popup to fight for focus, sending the CPU to 100%.  If I disable the browser in the popup form or hide it the problem doesn't occur.

Like I said it's only on some customer PCs but we can recreate it here on our PC with a Logitech combined keyboard / touchpad.

If you need a sample application I can provide one, along with the web page it navigates to.

We think we can get round it by disabling the browser then calling BringToFront() then re-enabling the browser but that's not ideal.

Comment: Try setting Focus Handler to null http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_FocusHandler.htm

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it still does the same thing:           ChromeBrowser.FocusHandler = null;

Comment: Integrating `CEF` into `WinForms` message loop would be the next step I'd try, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multithreadedmessageloop See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/75/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Program.cs#L63 for a working example.